# vestal_versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vestal-versions

I was watching railscasts episode 177, as I need to implement some versioning in my app. But this episode was not done in Rails 3. So i went to the site of the gem itself.

https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions

Now, it says it was tested with Rails 3, but even placing that line in the gemfile didn't let me install it. I just installed using gem install etc.

Now to even generate the migration is an issue, as I get the error

```
$ rails generate vestal_versions:migration
Could not find generator vestal_versions:migration.
```

Has anyone managed to succesfully use the gem that could give me advice?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Do you have this line in your Gemfile?

```
gem 'vestal_versions', :git => 'git://github.com/adamcooper/vestal_versions'
```

and ran `bundle install`? That's the one that is in the readme on github and works for me. I had the same error of the missing generator when I used

```
gem 'vestal_versions'
```

in my Gemfile, which fetches the gem from rubygems.org, which is pretty old and does not contain the proper generators yet. Using the gem from Github should work.

Btw, I'm not sure which fork on github is the best. There are several that do contain some fixes.

Comment: This worked for me too. I generally try to avoid git releases of gems but in this case it was the only thing that worked!